# How install python 3.7.7 on adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:x86_64-alpine-jdk-11.0.6_10?

Tags: java, python, docker, dockerfile

The dockerfile is:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:x86_64-alpine-jdk-11.0.6_10

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

# install base modules, python, node.js (java comes with)
RUN apk add --update-cache \
    bash \
    ttf-dejavu \
    python3==3.7.7 \
    build-base \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    git \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

And this gives me en error:

```
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  python3-3.8.10-r0:
    breaks: world[python3=3.7.7]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the error is in defining the specific version of python3.
You can set specific versions like this:

```
# Both are equal
apk add package=1.2.3-suffix
apk add 'package<1.2.3-suffix'
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://stschindler.medium.com/the-problem-with-docker-and-alpines-package-pinning-18346593e891 Alpine Linux most likely no longer has the package for 3.7.7 that you are asking for